How to refer to configured Datasource from my code (IntelliJ + Python)
I have Cassandra Datasource configured in my IntelliJ (as global).
I can manually establish a session and run CQL queries from console.
How do I do it from Python code without re-entering User ID and other parameters and referring to the Datasource instead?
This must a RTFM case but I could not find the answer.

There is no cross-integration between the Database tool and the Python interpreter.
Database tool allows you to inspect the data source and run queries against it, but the Python interpreter is a separate instance and one should use related Python db libraries to interact with the database like in any other Python script.
